# free Windows XP app to enforce user time restrictions

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

Does anyone know of any free Windows XP apps that will automatically log a user off if a set amount of logged in time is up?

Screen savers don't work if the user is still actively using the account, or if there is an application running full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get [Windows Steadystate](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=d077a52d-93e9-4b02-bd95-9d770ccdb431&displaylang=en).

But hurry because they're closing the download **midnight tonight**.

Comment: Perfect! I got it, got it setup and is exactly what I need. I also saved it in my Google docs :P Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict logon times without extra software via the command line:

e.g

```
net user john /times:su-sa,8am-5pm
```

I don't recall if this automatically logs the user off as well, but that can be achieved with a small script if that's not the case.

Comment: What kind of a simple script?

Comment: the %username% variable holds the currently logged in user. If %username% is equal to .... then `shutdown -l`.